# Copy all unique files from multiple directories into one. Rename duplicate names & preserve extension file.png, file (1).png

Tags: bash, rsync, cp

I'd like copy all unique files from multiple directories into one. Rename duplicate names & preserve extension file.png, file (1).png etc.

At least I'd like to merge all files from all directories and preserve extension. Obviously `rsync -b` — bad solution.
I can delete duplicate files after than by rdfind, for example.

Comment: What have you try so far? Hot to find if two files are duplicated?

Comment: Just find & delete duplicates files is simple `rdfind -deleteduplicates true ./`. But it's not what I want.